# Release an android app's new version that can be replaced by previous version

Tags: android

I have an app that I developed it in eclipse in debug mode and many users have installed it. Now I want to do a few changes in it and release a new version in android studio in release mode. How can I do this, so that it can be replaces by previous version and users data not lost ?

Comment: Have you already ported your project over to Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

For users to update from one version to another, the APK needs to be signed with the same keys and the package name of the application needs to remain the same.

If your debug builds are signed with a different key than your release builds, then you cannot provide an update to your users unless they uninstall the old version first.

If you uploaded the debug build to the Google Play Developer Console, then you are stuck using the debug key for future release unless you remove the old application from the Play Store and create a new one.

Comment: So I can't do this ?

Comment: You can, as long as the keys for signing remain the same as Tanis mentioned.

Comment: Unless you sign the two with the same key, no. This is a security feature- Android will not allow users to install an APK with the same package name as an existing application if it is signed with a different key. This prevents someone else from developing an app with the same package name as yours and installing it on users' devices.

Comment: I didn't understand what you are saying :(
What about If I have that debug.keystore file for previous version ?

Comment: If you signed the previous version with the debug.keystore file, then for your users to update you need to continue signing with the debug.keystore file.